# How to drop tcp packet in linux kernel but do not receive again and again?

Tags: c, tcp, linux-kernel, packet

I want to change the linux kernel code to filter some tcp packet and drop it.

But I always keep receiving it again and again. Here is my code in

/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c

```
int tcp_v4_do_rcv(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
// my code start
struct iphdr *iph;
iph = skb->nh.iph;

if(iph->ttl > 64) // I want to drop all tcp packet that meet this requirement
{
   return 0;
}
// my code end


// start normal linux code
  if(sk->sk_state == TCP_ESTABLISHED) { /* Fast path */
...
}
```

Comment: TCP is reliable, so the peer will naturally retransmit the packet when you drop it there. You should rather make a iptables/netfilter rule to drop these packets rather than altering the kernel though

Comment: I want to filter the packet for ttl per socket created by user. That's why I have to do it in kernel. Is it possible for iptables/netfilter to do it? In fact, I changed the structure of socket, add a ttl variable in it. The real code is:if(iph->ttl > sk->sk_myttlvalue) // I want to drop all tcp packet that meet this requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nos said, TCP is reliable, so the other end will retransmit the dropped packet. You would need to send a RST or an ICMP ERROR (probably host unreachable, administratively prohibited) to teardown the connection.

Also, note that you've created a memory leak, you're responsible for freeing skb's when you discard them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ttl module for iptables, which can filter by ttl:

```
iptables –A INPUT -m ttl --ttl-gt 65 –j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I set it up to work for only one opened socket?

Comment: @jie yan, you should find a properties uniq to this socket.  There are a lot of iptables tests and modules. I can help you if you can describe, what is "one opened socket"? If it long-living and you know its src-dst and ports - you can fix them in iptables rule. May be you should reask question

Comment: Now I describe the whole thing in detail:

Comment: Now I describe the whole thing in detail: The target is application want to create a socket and can call setsockopt to setup a ttl threshold for this socket to filter all TCP/IP packets that ttl is larger than this threshold. The application know the socket's src-dst and ports. Do you think it is better for application to use iptables instead of changing the kernel setsockopt function? Because the embedded linux kernel we are using does not have the iptable implementation. We need add it if we want to use iptable.

Comment: jie yan, thanks. Is this ttl limit different for each socket, or it is all the same? Do you need to limit only 1 application or several?

Comment: Not every socket need be set up ttl threshold value, but if set, it is always be the same value(e.g. 6), not the default value 64 most linux used. Only one application currently. The application creat other sockets but do not need set up ttl value.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to, you could modify the code to send an acknowledgment for the packet, but instead drop it. I don't really recommend this.